# how to get the url parameters from http

Tags: node.js

I am working in a very rudimentary "routing" system for small CMS in nodejs without express or any framework. My aim is to have very few dependencies. 
For templating I found jrender that works fine in the sample route "hey" below:

```
var http = require('http')
var jsrender = require ('jsrender');    

var html = jsrender.renderFile('./templates/hey.html', {name: "Jim", age: "22"});


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); // http header

    var url = req.url;
    if(url ==='/about'){
        console.log (req.url)
        res.write("hey"); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response

    }else if(url ==='/contact'){
        res.write('<h1>contact us page<h1>'); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response

    }else if(url ==='/hey'){
        res.write(html); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response    

    }else{
        res.write('<h1>Hello World!<h1>'); //write a response
        res.end(); //end the response
    }

}).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Judge Dress live on port 3000"); //the server object listens on port 3000
});
```

My problem is to get a parameter for a page e.g. /?pages=pagename to have dynamic routes. Is there any way to extact this parameter from req.url ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-access-query-string-parameters/ Etc. It's in the docs--you'll want to read them if you're reinventing wheels.

Comment: If you're not going to use any other modules (even built-in ones), then you just parse the query parameters yourself.  It's just a small bit of string manipulation.  If you do want to use built-in modules, then you can use [`url.parse()`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) and/or the [queryString](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module.

Comment: @devnull That "8+ year old article" is part of the NodeJS knowledge base. Both mechanisms are no-dependency ways to do what you asked for. So: that *is* the manual that provides the official docs for precisely what you asked for. I can't even.

Comment: @DaveNewton fair enough :)

Comment: @DaveNewton just re-read the "manual" example url.parse(req.url,true).search returns '?foo=bad&baz=foo'.   you see that this is not what I asked. The question is really if there is function that can give me the GET parameter and nothing else. in PHP is one line I can't believe I have to manipulate strings in node just to get that ?

Comment: @devnull Read harder: `url.parse('some.com/?url=hi&foo=bar', true)` returns a `query` property with key/value pairs as well as a bunch of other stuff. It's like two minutes in the REPL. If it *doesn't* then you're leaving out information required to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the node.js built-in 'querystring' module. To get "me" from "http://localhost:3000/about/?pages=me"

```
const querystring = require('querystring');     
console.log(querystring.parse(req.url)["/about/?pages"])
```

Comment: thanks but this gives me the whole sub-url url /about/?pages=me  how to get only "me" ? I did check query string in the manual and tried different delimiters but I still get /about?pages=me

Comment: @devnull try this querystring.parse(url)["/about/?pages"], to get "me"

Comment: No, that just abuses the URL and won't help for multiple parameters etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton you obviously have a lot of experience so perhaps -- not to reinvent the wheel -- which router would you use without a framework? In alternative for a small CMS is using http only not possible at all ? I don't plan to have multiple parameters.

Comment: @SudhakarRS that still returns /about/?pages=me

Comment: `queryString` doesn't parse URLs, it parses query strings.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `url` module does exactly what you're asking, as described in its docs:

```
> var url = require('url')
> url.parse('some.com/?url=hi&foo=bar', true)
Url {
  protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: '?url=hi&foo=bar',
  query: { url: 'hi', foo: 'bar' },
  pathname: 'some.com/',
  path: 'some.com/?url=hi&foo=bar',
  href: 'some.com/?url=hi&foo=bar' }
```

See the `query` property? Key/value pairs of the request parameters.

https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost

Answer (score 0):

```js
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

const app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    // Get information object about request URL:
    const parsedURL = url.parse(
        req.url, 
        true // 'true' sets parameters to be returned in object format
    );

    // Handle request to '/page' route:
    if (parsedURL.pathname === '/page') {

        // Get all parameters:
        console.log(parsedURL.query); // { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3' }
    
        // Get key1 parameter:
        console.log(parsedURL.query.key1); // value1

    }

    res.end();

});

app.listen(3000);
```

source https://openjavascript.info/2023/02/21/get-url-parameters-in-node-js/